# Measure L sweeping frequency

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductance

I have found the circuit below as a method to measure inductance.

My understanding is that we do a frequency sweep with the 555 timer. The LC tank, which is connected to the timer, will resonate at a certain frequency and thus the amplitude of the tank output will be maximum.

I don't quite understand the function of the diode connected in series with the resistor and the capacitor.

I have read that it is an envelope detector. From what I understand, an envelope detector outputs another signal and we want to measure the inductance from measuring DC voltage. I guess I don't quite understand how an envelope detector works. Any clarification on this?

[image]

My idea is to apply this method with an Arduino. Would there be any better way to measure inductance with Arduino?

Answer (score 2):

The diode and capacitor sense the amplitude of the peaks of the L.C resonance. The amplitude changes with frequency and will be a maximum at the resonant frequency.

If you measure the *frequency* of the 555 at the frequency where the amplitude reaches maximum, you can calculate the inductance.

You *could* control the frequency also with the Arduino - either of the 555 oscillator or just use the Arduino to drive the 555 as a buffer.

You would need to use the ADC to detect a peak at the diode output. Note that this circuit will generally need a load resistor (say 100 k) to ensure that after the e peak amplitude it detects the smaller signal.

You have to sweep the frequency slow enough to allow the resonance to grow, but this is unlikely to be a big issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "use the Arduino to drive the 555 as a buffer" means. Could you explain it to me a little?

Comment: And the Arduino itself couldn't do the frequency sweep with PWM?

Comment: delete all the components connected to pins 2,6,7. Connect 6 & 2 together and drive via PWM from the Arduino. Vary the PWM frequency with the Arduino... Alternatively, you might be able to eliminate the 555 and drive C3 directly with the Arduino's ouput.

Comment: Would it be a better option to drive the 555 timer via Arduino? Because I don't think Arduino is capable of doing a sweep as wide as the 555, a dedicated circuit...

Comment: It depends on your Arduino. A Teensy 3.x (pjrc.com) can do up to 10 MHz.